# How to declare aura:handler properly? (Application Event vs. Component Event)

Tags: lightning-aura-components

In my test project I'm trying to subscribe on Save Event using. Currently I'm using `force:refreshView` event to dispatch changes to my custom lightning component. I use this line and all works perfectly.

```
<aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.doInit}" />
```

But after that I tried to subscribe on `force:recordSaveSuccess` using similar syntax

```
<aura:handler event="force:recordSaveSuccess" action="{!c.handleSaveSuccess}"/>
```

But Developer Console doesn't allow to save and execute this script and Display an error

> Failed to save undefined: A aura:handler that specifies an event=""
>   attribute must handle an application event. Either change the
>   aura:event to have type="APPLICATION" or alternately change the
>   aura:handler to specify a name="" attribute.: Source

That literally mean that I need to add `name` attribute to this handler.

Could anyone explain why I can use `force:refreshView` without `name` attribute, but I have to add this attribute for `force:recordSaveSuccess`? I didn't find anything valuable in SF Lightning doc.

Answer (score 3):

In general component event requires `name` attribute to be defined in the `aura:handler`. See the [handling of component event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_component_handling_intro.htm) for more info.

Look at the doc on [force:recordSaveSuccess](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_recordSaveSuccess.htm) it pretty much clear that it is an component event, which is why it's handler without `name` defined threw an error.

Comment: why it's not required for `force:refreshView`?

Comment: @AdelNazirov It's because `force:refreshView` is an application event and it's Salesforce decision to keep it this way.